# Bootstrap Jumbotron stuttering

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with the Jumbotron on my [Ceredigion Actif](http://www.ceredigionactif.org.uk/index.html) homepage. They seem to stutter between each slide. It's only recently that I've had this problem because it worked fine when I originally set up the Jumbotron. News items are changing all the time on the homepage.

I've currently got four slides that need to be shown, each containing one image, a  heading and a paragraph. All images are the same height (189px) but have varying widths. Two of them are jpegs and two of them are pngs.

I've tried removing each slide separately to see if any of them were causing the issue but that hasn't had an effect. To my knowledge I've not changed any javascript since I set the page up.

[Screen shot of white space between slides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DReO2.jpg)

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't seem to reproduce this stuttering, to me it appears as though the styles for the slider are inconsistent as it is animating through the slides. for instance the `h1` element changes colour and spacing while it is animating and its class is `item active left`

As a quick fix for the white spaces between slides you can try this:

```
#slides {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```